# java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry for key when trying to insert in database from java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

this is my table in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`mytab` (

    `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`email`));
```

and my code in java is

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spacespacer", "root", "");
PreparedStatement state=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `spacespacer`.`mytab` VALUES (?, ?);");
state.setString(1, "email");
state.setString(2, "name");
state.executeUpdate();
```

and this is what i get when i run the file in netbeans

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry 'email' for key 'PRIMARY'
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1531)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:958)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1880)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1741)
at spacespacer.SpaceSpacer.main(SpaceSpacer.java:30)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

so how do i get it to work?

thanks for replying

Comment: Check the value that you are trying to insert and then check if it is already on the table. The error states that you are trying to insert the same value in a primary key field which only allows the value just once.

Comment: i solved this just by deleting the table from my local db, and then run, so hibernate will create the tables from the start, now its work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table you have already have an entry with "email".

Here in the table column email is set as PrimaryKey. So duplication cannot be possible.

*Note :*

Your Table is `mytab` under database `mydb`. But you are inserting into `spacespacer.mytab`.

Comment: oh ok, i already had a value named "email" in,
thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you already have "email" in your table which you have set as primary key. So you cannot add more emails called "email". Try querying your table to check if you already have that record. As a suggestion, don't use email as a primary key. It will result in slow indexing and searching since its a varchar and can be  long.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 'email' as key, even when it is unique. Rule of thumb, use `int` or `long` as primary key.

Comment: i could not retrieve the generated key in java when i use statement.getGeneratedKeys() it only shows the number of rows inserted in java, not the actual number of keys

Comment: @AminePaleo Use `ps = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)` and after `ps.executeUpdate()` you can get the generated keys in a resultset via `ps.getGeneratedKeys()`.